# R - Testing an installation

Tags: r, installation

I am new to R. I have just installed R 3.2.2, and RStudio 0.99, under Windows 8.

As per section **3.2 Testing an Installation** of *Help contents*, 
I meant to execute the following 5 lines of commands.

```
Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")
library("tools")
testInstalledBasic("both")
testInstalledPackages(scope = "base", errorsAreFatal = FALSE)
testInstalledPackages(scope = "recommended", errorsAreFatal = FALSE)
```

The first 2 worked fine. The third threw an error, as shown here

```
> Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")
> library("tools")
> testInstalledBasic("both")
running strict specific tests
  running code in ‘eval-etc.R’
unable to open output file
FAILED
[1] 1
Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD BATCH --vanilla --no-timing "eval-etc.R" "eval-etc.Rout"' had status 2 
>
```

What is the problem?
Could it be related to setting directories/permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the diff file from Rtools in the test folder. Simply copying/pasting should do the trick.